# NIST Randomess Test Running

Tags: random

I am trying to run NIST randomness testing on an Input file having 3645018 bits. I can see that it's giving correct frequencies of Zero's and One's but I am not able to get the results of other test. No one of the test is showing any P-value. I am giving bitstream=1. 
[image: Testing result screenshot]
Am I running it wrong or is there any other issue?